# Crystal Report - Printing information from sub-report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on a Crystal Report and if the address which is in a subreport is duplicate I need the information to print on the same page if it’s different I need it to print on a separate page....Please Help!

Comment: Show some code that we can look at. Otherwise, you won't get any help.

Answer (score 0):

Like AmmoPT said, we might need more information to help you.

But maybe you you can try this:
Right click on the section where the sub-report is: Section Expert - Paging .

Then on new page before, click the x-2 formula icon and use something like this:

if {your_adress_field}=previous({your_adress_field}) then false else true